# How to generate a features.xml for Karaf that take into consideration the already available features

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

So I have some simple webservices done using Camel and Apache CXF to run on a JBoss Fuse 6.3 Karaf installation. I want to automatically generate a features.xml to reduce the risks of mistakes and make it overall simpler, but I don't want to have a features.xml that ask to install bundles that are already provided by FUSE. Right now I'm using the features-maven-plugin but it create a features.xml with a bundle for each dependencies, including bundles that are already in FUSE.

How should I go about it? Does my request even make sense (I'm a total noob on OSGi)?

Comment: Are you able to solve your issue?

Comment: No, absolutely not, I found that installing bundles that are already provided by FUSE is not really an issue, but even listing all the bundles necessary from the Maven dependencies is not an easy task, with JBoss Fuse 6.3 I can only use features-maven-plugin because the newer karaf-maven-plugin doesn't support the old version of Karaf in this version of Fuse, and it doesn't work well, some bundles are missing from the list. So right now I'm doing everything manually.

Comment: I doubt this is possible but installing same bundle shouldn't be an issue anyway?

Comment: I think the way to solve your problem is to use a manually maintained feature file where you will be able to do that. I'm not sure if features-maven-plugin takes into consideration dependency scopes, but even if it does, it still works at maven dependencies level. Later versions of features plugin takes into consideration feature files which are dependencies of your project. Maybe it's worth checking that.